# Ho to set MPAndroid piechart no lable

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'v used MPAndroid PieChart and want to show only percent values without labels. When I remove labels then colored guide below of chart also is without label. How to remove labels from pichart without removing guide labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `setDrawLabels(false)` for the [axis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis).

> `setDrawLabels(boolean enabled)`: Set this to true to enable drawing the labels of the axis.

Comment: It shows 4 guide colors. How to increase it to shows all chart labels?